# Simplest way to manage a list of objects that can contain other objects

Tags: c#, list

Sorry for the title. I couldn't think of a better one for the life of me.

Anyways, here's what I'm having trouble with.
Let's say I have a list like this one

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
```

Now, based on some rule, I want to group elements from c to f so the list looks like.

```
[a, b, [c, d, e, f], g, h]
```

The original list has decreased in size to 5 elements (the inner list is of the same type as the singular values).

Now I could group it further and further to something like

```
[a, [b, [c, d, e, f]], [g, h]]
```

What I'm having trouble with is the actual implementation of it.
When I had to do it before I wrote a custom linked list (although C# provides one) that let me modify the left and right links of an element so I just took elements from c to f, stuck them in a new object and told b to point to it to the right and g to point to it to the left.

This, however, seems like a huge overkill and there's something telling me there has to be some easier, built-in solution in .NET for these types of things.

Comment: Why do you need to have the elements grouped as sub-groups? Could you just query the list to get the groups?

Comment: You almost certainly want to build your code on top of `IEnumerable`, rather than `LinkedList` (whether custom or library).  How do you want to define what element should be make into the subset?  Will you give a start and end index, a start index and count, a function that takes an item and returns a boolean indicating if it should be included in the previous group, what?

Comment: This is actually a part of a tokenizer. The elements can be numbers, operators and brackets. I want to group the brackets. Ideally, I'd group them by providing two indices.

Comment: Sounds like a tree rather than a list

Comment: Yeah. I guess you're right.